# Cleaned list has null elements

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I have a list of data object which has a list of results. I want to save all the lists of results with the same order in another list. However some of the list of results elements are null.

Before getting all string values I am cleaning the list:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        if (dataList.get(i).getResultList() == null) {
            dataList.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

Then I want to write into another list:

```
//double List to String
List<List<String>> ar_List = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dataList.get(i).getResultList().size(); j++) {
        if(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j) != null) {
            ar_List.get(i).add(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString());
        } else {
            ar_List.get(i).add("null");
        }
    }
}
```

However I get a `NullPointerException` at `if(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j) != null) {`. Thats because some of the dataList objects are null. However this cannot be possible, because I cleaned the list before. Any suggestions?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

Using:

```
    for (int i = dataList.size()-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        if (dataList.get(i).getResultList() == null) {
            dataList.remove(i);
        }
    }

            List<List<String>> ar_List = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataList.get(i).getResultList().size(); j++) {
            if(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j) != null) {
                ar_List.get(i).add(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString());
            } else {
                ar_List.get(i).add("null");
            }
        }
    }
```

results in a:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:` at `ar_List.get(i).add(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in the removing part. You are removing list items so your list will be getting changed and it will skip some of the items from being cleaned. You can either use iterator or remove items backward like below:

You can replace:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        if (dataList.get(i).getResultList() == null) {
            dataList.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

with

```
   for (int i = dataList.size()-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        if (dataList.get(i).getResultList() == null) {
            dataList.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is happening because your ar_list does not have any item and you are trying to get item at index i. correct your code.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! I would appreciate your suggestions on how to possibly fix that problem.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) { 
 //Create a new list of string here say with the name mylist
        for (int j = 0; j < dataList.get(i).getResultList().size(); j++) {
            if(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j) != null) {
                mylist.add(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString());
            } else {
                mylist.get(i).add("null");
            }
        }
 // add my list to ar_list
    }` You can remove null handling as we have a cleaned list now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the forLoop which causes the problem. Instead use the iterator to remove the unwanted elements in the List

```
for (E element : list) {
    // 1 - can call methods of element

    // ...
}
```

Assume you have a List `[0:item, 1:null, 2: null, 3: item]`

Loop 1: no deletes `[0:item, 1:null, 2: null, 3: item]`

Loop 2: deletes item @ index 1 ' `[0:item, 1:null, 2: item]`

Loop 3: no deletes as item @ index 2 is valid  `[0:item, 1:null, 2: item]`

so when you loop again in a fresh for loop, the null at index 1 causes the NPE.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: @user503413 The problem is that I am getting a NPE, however my first piece of code shows that I am cleaning the list for null elements. So why am I getting a NPE?

Comment: Thx for your answer theCoder however I think I am still doing that with my for loop. Where is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The problem come from the fact that you are not cleaning correctly the list.

Every time you remove a null result list, if the one just after is null as well, then it will not be checked.

Quick fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
    if (dataList.get(i).getResultList() == null) {
        dataList.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
List<List<String>> ar_List = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

When you're using your it, the list is empty, so when you calling: `ar_List.get(i)` Java will thrown an IndexOutOfBoundsException as said in the javadoc:
>

> get
>
> E get(int index)
>
> Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
>
> Parameters:
>          index - index of the element to return
>
> Returns:
>          the element at the specified position in this list
>
> Throws:
>          IndexOutOfBoundsException - **if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())**

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list {"value", null, null, "value"}, then remove null at index 1 there will be another null at index 1, but you continue checking at index 2.

When you delete objects by index, you will have to decrement the index afterwards. try
`dataList.remove(i--);`